# Which will be faster out of these two queries?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (1,2,3)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 1 OR col = 2 OR col = 3
```

Comment: DB? Did you profile?

Comment: Can we assume from his dolphin icon that he's referring to MySQL?  ;)

Comment: Readability is probably more worth the trouble than the very few milliseconds you'll save by using the "best" one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same.

**Edit**: They are the same in MySQL.

*using an index:*

```
mysql> explain select * from trees where id = 1 or id = 2;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | trees | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+

mysql> explain select * from trees where id in (1,2);
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | trees | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

*using a full table scan:*

```
mysql> explain select * from trees where version = 1 or version = 2;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | trees | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+

mysql> explain select * from trees where version in (1,2);
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | trees | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: I thought `IN (whatever)` just translated out to multiple `OR` tests, so it seems like they would be the same.

Comment: It doesn't seem unlikely when it comes to execution plan. It depends on how DBMS decides to optimize the query.

Comment: E.g. sql server, the in clause does get to translated a series of ORs

Comment: Saying that it seems unlikely isn't a very helpful comment. +1 for post as these do come out the same in MySQL which we believe the question was directed towards.

Comment: So wouldn't the IN statement be a fraction slower than the OR's since the db engine would need to make the translation?

Comment: @Adam: that is a micro(nano, pico)fraction of processing time, and the engine will anyway cache the query after the first execution. It shouldn't really make any difference.

Comment: @Adam: Technically the optimiser doesn't translate 'one into the other'. Both queries are translated into a the same 'internal plan'.

Answer (score 3):

With most RDBMSs the queries are processed through an optimizer before execution. And since your predicates are logically equivalent i would expect them to execute at the same speed because they will be optimized to execute in the same manner.

But it is db dependent. You didn't specify which engine you're using.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the interpretation of the database vendor and how they represent the where statements.

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft SQL Server, I believe they are interpreted in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2):

likely or not, but true...  Most databases convert the former syntax to the latter. Why wouldn't it?  They are logically and functiuonally identical.

See [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31664165/in-vs-or.aspx)

Comment: Because there could be faster ways of doing this depending on how data is internally represented and how the engine is designed. The difference would, still, likely be minimalistic.

Comment: No matter how data is represented internally, these two queries are semantically, logically, and functionally identical.  No matter how many ways the processor might be able to do them, it can do either of them in any of the many ways it could do the other one.

Comment: To make an absolutely identical analogy, it would be as if the language allowed you to either say "Where ColumnName = 'bob'" or "Where ColumnName equals 'bob'"  -------- or, and this IS the case in many databases, "Where ColumnName != 'Bob'"   Or "Where ColumnName <> 'bob'"

Answer (score 2):

Run EXPLAIN SELECT ... on both.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is: depends on the engine. Use EXPLAIN to check what's going on.

Some databases will translate IN form to a series of ORed clauses. Others will not.

Postgres for example gives a lower (!) cost when using the IN form.

I'd personally go for a first form as (1) some engines may optimize it, (2) it's more
intuitive, (3) is shorter.

Somewhat offtopic: please don't be tempted to overuse IN for joining the tables though. I've seen many times constructs like this:

SELECT * FROM employee WHERE boss_id IN (SELECT id FROM boss WHERE some_condition..)

I guess the reason for it is that somebody goes with the outer select, then finds out the condition in the referenced table by issuing the inner select, then just does copy & paste. Of course such construct is worse than the proper JOIN.

Comment: And why could an optimizer not flatten that join?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the queries are equivalents or the first one will be a little faster in a test.
Certain optimizations are applicable to comparisons that use the IN operator from a subquery which is not the case here.